# Wap a program to print 3 rows and 3 columns from 1 to 12 in php

Tags: php

I want to print number from 1 to 12 in matrix form and expected output is:

```
1 5 9 
2 6 10
3 7 11
4 8 12
```

code:

```
<?php   
for ($i=1; $i<=12; $i++)    
{    
    for($j=1;$j<=$i;$j++)     
    {       
        echo $i." ";     
    }       
    echo "<br/>";       
}  
?>
```

I have got wrong output. So, How can I get expected output as I mention above? Please help me.

Thank You

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some "magic" code):

```
foreach (range(1,4) as $num) {
    echo implode(' ', range($num,12,4)) . '<br />';
}
```

Version with `for`:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 4; $i++) {
    for ($j = $i; $j <= 12; $j +=4) {
        echo $j . ' ';
    }
    echo '<br />';
}
```

Comment: Please replace PHP_EOL with `<br/>`.

Comment: @Pupil thanks, fixed. Also added version with `for`.

Comment: I like the double use of `range`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$z=0;
   for ($x = 1; $x <= 4; $x++) 
{
       echo " $x ";
       $z=$x;
            for ($y = 1; $y <= 2; $y++) 
{
                $z=$z+4;
                echo " $z ";
            }
        echo "\n";
    }
```

Comment: Above code is another solution as per my logic

Answer (score 0):

$maxRow = 4;

$maxColumn = 3;

```
for ($row = 1; $row <= $maxRow; $row++)
{
    for ($column = 1; $column <= $maxColumn; $column++) {
        $number = $row + 4*($column-1);
        echo $number." ";
    }

    echo "<br/>";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

should work

```
foreach (range(1, 4) as $res) {
    echo implode(' ', range($res, 12, 4));
    echo "<br>";
}
```